# executar automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tenho um código onde vou precisar ter uma página de processamento, e nessa página vou precisar executar uma function javascript automaticamente.

Atualmente, executo essa function clicando, assim:

```
<input type="button" id="listarFipe" value="Listar Veiculos Fipe" />
```

minha função:

```
$(function() {
    $('#listarFipe').click(function() {
        var categorias = new Array();
        var carros = new Array();
        var potencia = new Array();
        var valvulas = new Array();
        var filtroMotor = new Array();
        var filtroValvula = new Array();

            //select montadora
              mont = document.form.montadora.selectedIndex; 
              montadora = document.form.montadora[mont].value; 

              AnoI = document.form.AnoInicial.selectedIndex; 
              AnoInicial = document.form.AnoInicial[AnoI].value;

              AnoF = document.form.AnoFinal.selectedIndex; 
              AnoFinal = document.form.AnoFinal[AnoF].value;


            //alert(j);



        $('input[id=montadora]:checked').each(function() {
            categorias.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('input[id=veiculo]:checked').each(function() {
            carros.push($(this).attr('class'));
        });
        $('input[id=potencias]:checked').each(function() {
            potencia.push($(this).attr('class'));
        });
        $('input[id=valvulas]:checked').each(function() {
            valvulas.push($(this).attr('class'));
        });     

        $('input[id=filtroMotor]:checked').each(function() {
            filtroMotor.push($(this).val());
        });
        $('input[id=filtroValvula]:checked').each(function() {
            filtroValvula.push($(this).val());
        });     

        //alert('getModeloFipe.php?montadora='+montadora+'&veiculos='+carros+'&motor='+potencia+'&valvulas='+valvulas+'&anoini='+AnoInicial+'&anofim='+AnoFinal+'&filtroMotor='+filtroMotor+'&filtroValvula='+filtroValvula);
        var url='getModeloFipe.php?montadora='+montadora+'&veiculos='+carros+'&motor='+potencia+'&valvulas='+valvulas+'&anoini='+AnoInicial+'&anofim='+AnoFinal+'&filtroMotor='+filtroMotor+'&filtroValvula='+filtroValvula;
        /*
        var url ='getModeloFipe.php?montadora='+montadora+'&veiculos='+carros+'&motor='+potencia+'&valvulas='+valvulas+'&AnoInicial='+AnoInicial+'&AnoFinal='AnoFinal;
        */
        //enviar para url ajax
          $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
          $('#checkVeiculosFipe').html(dataReturn);
        });
    });
});
```

Testei uma possível solução que encontrei na net:

```
$( "#assinar" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Ou alterar a sua função de javascript do click de:

```
$("#assinar").click(function(){
...
```

Para:

```
function processaAssinar() {
...
```

e chamar a função `processaAssinar()` logo depois que terminar o seu processamento.

Comment: Queres dizer que queres correr essa funcão anónima que o click faz correr, mas quando a página carrega e sem ser dependente de um click?

Comment: sim correto, essa função está em uma página de edição do cadastro, preciso que ela seja carregada automaticamente

Comment: Então é só remover `$('#listarFipe').click(` e o ultimo `)` ficando somente: `function processaAssinar() {` em vez de `$('#listarFipe').click(function() {`. Já testaste isso?

Comment: Coloca num jsFiddle o código que fizeste. Não vejo no teu comentário...

Comment: Já havia testado, mas testei novamente ficando assim: <pre>function listarFipe() { </pre> e testei assim tambem <pre>$(function() {
function listarFipe() {</pre>  eu preciso colocar essa funcao para carregar automaticamente na página, não necessitando clicar para chamá-la

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/inforicky/u7qhf6ra/

Comment: Ok, então só falta correr/chamar a função... juntando `listarFipe();` no final. -> http://jsfiddle.net/u7qhf6ra/1/

Comment: Você tem a opão de trocar sua function por $(document).ready(function(){...}). A function será executada assim que o documento for carregado

Comment: Dúvida solucionada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use um Module *Pattern*, que consiste em colocar sua função entre `()`, e depois colocar no fim novamente `()` porém vazio, segue um exemplo:

Execução normal:

```
function exemplo() {
 alert('exemplo');
} 

exemplo();
```

Usando Module Pattern:

```
(function exemplo() {

 alert('exemplo');

})()
```

Dessa forma ela vai se tornar auto executável.

Comment: o recurso *Module Pattern* também é conhecido como *self executing anonymous function*